# node-webkit with MEAN.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit, mean.io, vert.x

Is it possible to use node-webkit with MEAN.js (Or mean.io) ? I want to develop simple application using node-webkit and MEAN.js. Can I have some recommendation for that use-case.

**EDIT**

To create API with mean.js and then use it inside of Angular.js Factory (on node-webkit) ?

Is it possible to use vertx.io as backend and node-webkit + angularjs as technology for client side ?

**P.S.**
 *Why MEAN.js (I have background in using MEAN.js full-stack for developing web-app's. I want to know how to integrate it with node-webkit. I love MEAN's folder structure.*

Answer (score 0):

Late for the answer but maybe helps anothers:
[Wean Generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-wean) is not an equivalent to MEAN.js or MEAN.io but is posible to add the 'M' (MongoDB) easily I think. Or maybe you didn´t need MongoDB at all.

It´s inspired in [Slush Wean](https://github.com/arvindr21/slush-wean) and maybe that fits more your needs. Instead of MongoDB, it uses [NeDB](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb)